# ActiveResource model is not getting initialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

I am looking at using ActiveResource but is now facing a problem that I am unable to figure out myself (was searching the net for a couple of days for the solution by now).

So I have an authentication app sitting at `http://localhost:80` and a client on port :85

### In my auth app

I have a User model with its controller which follows REST architecture and is set to respond to xml calls.

Here is what I have in my auth app:

*models/User.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

*controllers/users_controller.rb*

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
respond_to :html, :xml, :js

def index
    @users = User.find :all
    respond_with @users
end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @user
end
.
.
.
end
```

### In a client application

I have a class extending from active resource as follows:

*models/user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveResource::Base
    self.site = "http://localhost:80"
end
```

Here is how I am trying to use it:
*controllers/sessions_controller.rb*

```
class SessionController < ApplicationController

  def home
    @user = User.find(:all)
  end
end
```

what could go wrong, right?..

But then I am getting the following error:

> Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-02 08:33:44 +1200 Processing
>   by SessionsController#home as HTML Completed 500 Internal Server Error
>   in 3ms
>
> NameError (uninitialized constant ActiveResource):
>   app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>
>   app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:4:in`home'
>
> Rendered
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb
>   (1.6ms)   Rendered
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb
>   (2.7ms)   Rendered
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb
>   (2.2ms)   Rendered
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (37.4ms)

I am using:

ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]
Rails 4.0.0
activeresource (4.0.0) gem is installed

**What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Is it possible that ActiveResource failing to connect to `localhost:80` and as a result does not get initialized?**

EDIT:

done rvm use 2.0.0 so now ruby version is: ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [i686-linux]

EDIT:

> RubyGems Environment:
>     - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.7
>     - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-10-30 patchlevel 0) [i686-linux]
>     - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
>     - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
>     - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
>     - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
>       - ruby
>       - x86-linux
>     - GEM PATHS:
>        - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
>        - /home/dmitry/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
>     - GEM CONFIGURATION:
>        - :update_sources => true
>        - :verbose => true
>        - :backtrace => false
>        - :bulk_threshold => 1000
>     - REMOTE SOURCES:
>        - https://rubygems.org/

Comment: Have you added the activeresource gem to the Gemfile of your client app or your auth app? or both?

Comment: Yes I have added this gem to both applications.. double-checked it now...

Comment: If you enter the Rails console (`rails console` from command line) and you type `ActiveResource`, what is returned?

Comment: Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)

2.0.0 :001 > ActiveResource

NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveResource
 from (irb):1
 from /home/dmitry/www/TestClient/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
 from /home/dmitry/www/TestClient/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
 from /home/dmitry/www/TestClient/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
 from bin/rails:4:in `require'
 from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Comment: `ActiveResource` is not being loaded into your environment. Does it show up if you type `bundle list activeresource` from command line (from within the environment upon which you're running Rails)?

Comment: bundle list returns: /home/dmitry/www/ac/TestClient/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeresource-4.0.0

Comment: which is wierd... it shows ruby/1.9.1 when command ruby -v returns 2.0.0... ruby/2.0.0/gems does have activeresource gem in it... could this be a problem? how can I set bundle to use my ruby 2.0.0 folder?

Comment: added 'gem env' output into my question body

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have finally figured this out...

For some reason (**I would be grateful if someone can post an explanation why**) I had to require active resource manually in my user.rb file.

The correct code to make it work should be:

```
require 'active_resource'  

class User < ActiveResource::Base  
    self.site = "http://localhost:80"  
end
```

P.S
Thank you [zeantsoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1086529/zeantsoi) for your comments, those have led me into a search for reasons of this gem not being loaded.

Answer (score 16):

In your `Gemfile` add the activeresource gem like so:

```
gem 'activeresource', require: 'active_resource'
```

This will make it behave as it should - without having to require it at the beginning of every activeresource model.

Answer (score 10):

`ActiveResource` should be loaded in your `config/application.rb` file:

```
# config/application.rb
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require 'active_resource/railtie'
require "action_controller/railtie"
...
```

In this case you will be able to configure `ActiveResource` later in the same file, for example:

```
# config/application.rb
module TestClient
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.active_resource.include_format_in_path = false
    config.active_resource.site = "http://localhost:80"
    ...
```

This is handy if you want to set some default options for all your `ActiveResource` models and of course you can override any of these options for some specific model:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveResource::Base
  self.include_format_in_path = true # append .json at the end of url
end
```